# Android ViewPager doesn't remove old views from screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to add a pageviewer to my app that simply show some images that explaing how the app work but I'm encountering a lot of problem...
The first page it's correctly showed but when I drag to next pages all pages that I've just seen stay in background and it's cause weird visualization.

Here my code...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ViewPagerActivity extends Activity {
private static int NUM_VIEWS = 5;

private MyPagerAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager pager;
private int[] pics = { R.drawable.bookmarks, R.drawable.bookmarks_click, R.drawable.help,
        R.drawable.help_click, R.drawable.logo_wil };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager);

    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mypager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_VIEWS;
    }

    /**
     * Create the page for the given position. The adapter is responsible
     * for adding the view to the container given here, although it only
     * must ensure this is done by the time it returns from
     * {@link #finishUpdate()}.
     * 
     * @param container
     *            The containing View in which the page will be shown.
     * @param position
     *            The page position to be instantiated.
     * @return Returns an Object representing the new page. This does not
     *         need to be a View, but can be some other container of the
     *         page.
     */
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        ImageView view = new ImageView(ViewPagerActivity.this);
        view.setImageResource(pics[position]);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a page for the given position. The adapter is responsible for
     * removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure
     * this is done by the time it returns from {@link #finishUpdate()}.
     * 
     * @param container
     *            The containing View from which the page will be removed.
     * @param position
     *            The page position to be removed.
     * @param object
     *            The same object that was returned by
     *            {@link #instantiateItem(View, int)}.
     */

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((ImageView) view);          
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    /**
     * Called when the a change in the shown pages has been completed. At
     * this point you must ensure that all of the pages have actually been
     * added or removed from the container as appropriate.
     * 
     * @param container
     *            The containing View which is displaying this adapter's
     *            page views.
     */
    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
    }


}

}
```

Comment: you can set off screen pages using the method of viewpager. It will compulsory create 2 pages: 1 is before the current page and other is after the current page.

Comment: Can you explain _"stay in background and it's cause weird visualization"_ more clearly?

Comment: @Amulya Khare The first time I view image1 correctly, when a swipe to right (for example) I view image2 and near image1 and not only image2.

Comment: @Sandy I've tried but nothing change...

Comment: So sorry.. but what happens after you swipe to the right? I don't get _"and near image1 and not only image2"_ You see them on top of each other? Side by side? or what?

Comment: @Amulya Scuse me for mine imprecision. I can see them side by side. And during swipe I view more copy of them moving in background.

Comment: DId you solve this? Having the same problem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833468/tabhost-first-loaded-tab-stays-in-background-after-switching-tabs